# Yocto: how to remove/blacklist some dependency from RDEPENDS of a package?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, imx6

I have a custom machine layer based on https://github.com/jumpnow/meta-wandboard.

I've upgraded the kernel to 4.8.6 and want to add X11 to the image.
I'm modifying to image recipe (`console-image.bb`).
Since wandboard is based on i.MX6, I want to include the `xf86-video-imxfb-vivante` package from `meta-fsl-arm`.
However, it fails complaining about inability to build `kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv`. I believe that happens because `xf86-video-imxfb-vivante` DEPENDS on `imx-gpu-viv` which in turn RDEPENDS on `kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv`.

I realize that those dependencies have been created with meta-fsl-arm BSP and vanilla Poky distribution. But those things are way outdated for wandboard, hence I am using the custom machine layer with modern kernel.
The kernel is configured to include the Vivante DRM module and I really don't want the `kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv` package to be built.

Is there a way to exclude it from RDEPENDS? Can I somehow swear my health to the build system that I will take care of this specific run-time dependency myself?

I have tried blacklisting 'kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv' setting `PNBLACKLIST[kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv]` in my local.conf, but that's just a part of a solution. It helps avoid build failures, but the packaging process still fails.

Comment: can you paste a log of log.do_package and run.do_package for me ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IIUC you problem comes from these lines in [`img-gpu-viv` recipe](https://github.com/Freescale/meta-fsl-arm/blob/a20f3344c564a0f388fe81c9c4f9aa6747e72578/recipes-graphics/imx-gpu-viv/imx-gpu-viv.inc):

```
FILES_libgal-mx6 = "${libdir}/libGAL${SOLIBS} ${libdir}/libGAL_egl${SOLIBS}"
FILES_libgal-mx6-dev = "${libdir}/libGAL${SOLIBSDEV} ${includedir}/HAL"
RDEPENDS_libgal-mx6 += "kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv"
INSANE_SKIP_libgal-mx6 += "build-deps"
```

I would actually qualify this `RDEPENDS` as a bug, usually kernel module dependencies are specified as `RRECOMMENDS` because most modules can be compiled into the kernel thus making no separate package at all while still providing the functionality. But that's another issue.

There are several ways to fix this problem, the first general route is to tweak RDEPENDS for the package. It's just a bitbake variable, so you can either [assign it some other value](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#basic-variable-setting) or [remove some portion of it](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#removing-override-style-syntax). In the first case it's going to look somewhat like this:

```
RDEPENDS_libgal-mx6 = ""
```

In the second one:

```
RDEPENDS_libgal-mx6_remove = "kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv"
```

Obviously, these two options have different implications for your present and future work. In general I would opt for the softer one which is the second, because it has less potential for breakage when you're to update `meta-fsl-arm` layer, which can change `imx-gpu-viv` recipe in any kind of way. But when you're overriding some more complex recipe with big lists in variables and you're modifying it heavily (not just removing a thing or two) it might be easier to maintain it with full hard assignment of variables.

Now there is also a question of *where* to do this variable mangling. The main option is [`.bbappend` in your layer](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-bbappend-files), that's what appends are made for, but you can also do this from your distro configuration (if you're maintaining your own distro it might be easier to have all these tweaks in one place, rather than sprayed into numerous appends) or from your `local.conf` (which is a nice place to quickly try it out, but probably not something to use in longer term). I usually use `.bbappend`.

But there is also a completely different approach to this problem, rather than fixing package dependencies you can also fix what [some other package provides](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-RPROVIDES). If for example you have a kernel configured to have `imx-gpu-viv` module built right into the main zimage you can do

```
RPROVIDES_kernel-image += "kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv"
```

(also in `.bbappend`, distro configuration or `local.conf`) and that's it.

In any case your approach to fixing this problem should reflect the difference between your setup and recipe assumptions. If you do have the module, but in a different package, then go for `RPROVIDES`, if you have some other module providing the same functionality to `libgal-mx6` package then fix `libgal-mx6` dependencies (and it's better to *fix* them, meaning not only drop something you don't need, but also add things that are relevant for your setup).

Comment: Thank you so much for this thoroughly elaborated answer! Although I realized that I was going a completely wrong way because modern kernels went the KMS and 'etnaviv' way for i.MX6, your answer is anyway extremely helpful. I didn't know about the `_remove` suffix, so I used a python code to do the same thing. Your solution is much cleaner. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in the newer yocto version , use

```
RDEPENDS_REMOVE:libgal-mx6 = "kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv"
```

to do the same thing as above.